# Get values from LoggerConfiguration()

Tags: c#

I need to write to file the values LoggerConfiguration() has read from config because
it is deployed to a container and does not do what I intend there.
In Visual studio I did a watch of two of the values, but when I try to copy
the watch statements in to Visual studio I get error messages.
If there was a way to dump the entire content to a file that would be great,
but for now I only need these two values:

```
private readonly ILogger _myLogger;   
_myLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("App", "App1")
                .CreateLogger();

string a = ((Serilog.Core.Enrichers.PropertyEnricher(Serilog.Core.Logger)_myLogger)._enricher)._value;

string hostname = ((Serilog.Sinks.Syslog.SyslogTcpSink)((Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink)((Serilog.Core.Sinks.SafeAggregateSink)((Serilog.Core.Logger)_myLogger)._sink)._sinks[0])._batchedLogEventSink).Host;
```

I get these error messages when I compile:

Error CS1061 'Logger' does not contain a definition for '_enricher' and no accessible extension method '_enricher' accepting a first argument of type 'Logger' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error CS0122 'SafeAggregateSink' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Error CS1061 'Logger' does not contain a definition for '_sink' and no accessible extension method '_sink' accepting a first argument of type 'Logger' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you need to provide the declation of `_enricher`, `SafeAggregateSink` and `_sink`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I get the error "Logger does not contain a definition for _sink and no accessible extension method _sink acceptin a first argument of type Logger could be found". SafeAggregateSink is inaccessible due to its protection level. Is there a way to dump all the variables in _myLogger to a file?

Comment: you should first answer my question what details I have asked you to provide